# How to set output_keep_prob of a DropoutWrapper in a graph restored from file

Tags: tensorflow

I've built and trained a model using DropoutWrapper around LSTM. The model was saved and later restored for testing on new data. I want to change the dropout to the test mode (output_keep_prob = 1.0). but can't figure out how to find it. I don't see anything like that in my restored graph.

Thanks!

(I accept the answer and have found that this question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971349/how-to-turn-off-dropout-for-testing-in-tensorflow))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can; make this a parameter like a placeholder with default or a variable and set it through that mechanism.