# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, dropout

I am trying to train a LSTM and in my model I have an exponential learning rate decay and a dropout layer. In order to deactivate the dropout layer when testing and validating, I have put a placeholder for the dropout rate and given it a default value of 1.0 and when training i am setting it to 0.5. The dropou_rate placeholder value is passed to the tf.layers.dropout(). When I run this during the validation I get the following error.

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float64').

shown below is the stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/suleka/Documents/sales_prediction/SalesPrediction_LSTM_mv.py",
>   line 329, in 
>       train_test()   File "/home/suleka/Documents/sales_prediction/SalesPrediction_LSTM_mv.py",
>   line 270, in train_test
>       meanSquaredError = mean_squared_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)   File
>   "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py",
>   line 238, in mean_squared_error
>       y_true, y_pred, multioutput)   File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/regression.py",
>   line 77, in _check_reg_targets
>       y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False)   File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
>   line 453, in check_array
>       _assert_all_finite(array)   File "/home/suleka/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py",
>   line 44, in _assert_all_finite
>       " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype) ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

When I put the learning rate as a value in  tf.layers.dropout like:

> dropout = tf.layers.dropout(last, rate=0.5, training=True)

The code works fine. I am not sure what is happening in the code.

Shown below is my complete code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib as mplt
mplt.use('agg')  # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from math import sqrt
import csv
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)


class RNNConfig():
    input_size = 1
    num_steps = 7#5
    lstm_size = 64 #16
    num_layers = 1
    keep_prob = 0.8
    batch_size = 16 #64
    init_epoch = 15  # 5
    max_epoch = 20 # 100 or 50
    # test_ratio = 0.2
    fileName = 'store2_1.csv'
    graph = tf.Graph()
    column_min_max = [[0,11000], [1,7]]
    columns = ['Sales', 'DayOfWeek','SchoolHoliday', 'Promo']
    features = len(columns)
    hidden1_nodes = 64
    hidden2_nodes = 8



config = RNNConfig()

def segmentation(data):

    seq = [price for tup in data[config.columns].values for price in tup]

    seq = np.array(seq)

    # split into items of features
    seq = [np.array(seq[i * config.features: (i + 1) * config.features])
           for i in range(len(seq) // config.features)]

    # split into groups of num_steps
    X = np.array([seq[i: i + config.num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  config.num_steps)])

    y = np.array([seq[i +  config.num_steps] for i in range(len(seq) -  config.num_steps)])

    # get only sales value
    y = [[y[i][0]] for i in range(len(y))]

    y = np.asarray(y)

    return X, y

def scale(data):

    for i in range (len(config.column_min_max)):
        data[config.columns[i]] = (data[config.columns[i]] - config.column_min_max[i][0]) / ((config.column_min_max[i][1]) - (config.column_min_max[i][0]))

    return data

def rescle(test_pred):

    prediction = [(pred * (config.column_min_max[0][1] - config.column_min_max[0][0])) + config.column_min_max[0][0] for pred in test_pred]

    return prediction


def pre_process():
    store_data = pd.read_csv(config.fileName)

    store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open == 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)
    #
    # store_data = store_data.drop(store_data[(store_data.Open != 0) & (store_data.Sales == 0)].index)

    # ---for segmenting original data --------------------------------
    # original_data = store_data.copy()

    ## train_size = int(len(store_data) * (1.0 - test_ratio))

    validation_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 6) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    test_len = len(store_data[(store_data.Month == 7) & (store_data.Year == 2015)].index)
    train_size = int(len(store_data) - (validation_len + test_len))

    train_data = store_data[:train_size]
    validation_data = store_data[(train_size - config.num_steps): validation_len + train_size]
    test_data = store_data[((validation_len + train_size) - config.num_steps):]
    original_val_data = validation_data.copy()
    original_test_data = test_data.copy()

    # -------------- processing train data---------------------------------------
    scaled_train_data = scale(train_data)
    train_X, train_y = segmentation(scaled_train_data)

    # -------------- processing validation data---------------------------------------
    scaled_validation_data = scale(validation_data)
    val_X, val_y = segmentation(scaled_validation_data)

    # -------------- processing test data---------------------------------------
    scaled_test_data = scale(test_data)
    test_X, test_y = segmentation(scaled_test_data)

    # ----segmenting original validation data-----------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_val_X, nonescaled_val_y = segmentation(original_val_data)

    # ----segmenting original test data---------------------------------------------
    nonescaled_test_X, nonescaled_test_y = segmentation(original_test_data)

    return train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, val_X, val_y, nonescaled_test_y, nonescaled_val_y


def generate_batches(train_X, train_y, batch_size):
    num_batches = int(len(train_X)) // batch_size
    if batch_size * num_batches < len(train_X):
        num_batches += 1

    batch_indices = range(num_batches)
    for j in batch_indices:
        batch_X = train_X[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        batch_y = train_y[j * batch_size: (j + 1) * batch_size]
        assert set(map(len, batch_X)) == {config.num_steps}
        yield batch_X, batch_y

def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    itemindex = np.where(y_true == 0)
    y_true = np.delete(y_true, itemindex)
    y_pred = np.delete(y_pred, itemindex)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100

def RMSPE(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(((y_true - y_pred) / y_pred)), axis=0))

def plot(true_vals,pred_vals,name):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig = plt.figure(dpi=100, figsize=(20, 7))
    days = range(len(true_vals))
    plt.plot(days, pred_vals, label='pred sales')
    plt.plot(days, true_vals, label='truth sales')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
    plt.xlabel("day")
    plt.ylabel("sales")
    plt.grid(ls='--')
    plt.savefig(name, format='png', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=False)
    plt.close()

def write_results(true_vals,pred_vals,name):

    with open(name, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(zip(true_vals, pred_vals))


def train_test():
    train_X, train_y, test_X, test_y, val_X, val_y, nonescaled_test_y, nonescaled_val_y = pre_process()


    # Add nodes to the graph
    with config.graph.as_default():

        tf.set_random_seed(1)

        learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, name="learning_rate")
        inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, config.num_steps, config.features], name="inputs")
        targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, config.input_size], name="targets")
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
        dropout_rate = tf.placeholder_with_default(1.0, shape=())

        learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate=learning_rate, global_step=global_step, decay_rate=0.96,  decay_steps=5, staircase=False)

        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(config.lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True, activation=tf.nn.relu)

        val1, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32)

        val = tf.transpose(val1, [1, 0, 2])

        last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1, name="last_lstm_output")


        # hidden layer
        last = tf.layers.dense(last, units=config.hidden1_nodes, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        last = tf.layers.dense(last, units=config.hidden2_nodes, activation=tf.nn.relu)



        weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([config.hidden2_nodes, config.input_size]))
        bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[config.input_size]))

        dropout = tf.layers.dropout(last, rate=dropout_rate, training=True)

        prediction = tf.matmul(dropout, weight) + bias

        loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(targets,prediction)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
        minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

        # correct_prediction = tf.sqrt(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(prediction, targets))


    # --------------------training------------------------------------------------------

    with tf.Session(graph=config.graph) as sess:
        tf.set_random_seed(1)

        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

        iteration = 1


        for epoch_step in range(config.max_epoch):


            for batch_X, batch_y in generate_batches(train_X, train_y, config.batch_size):
                train_data_feed = {
                    inputs: batch_X,
                    targets: batch_y,
                    learning_rate: 0.01,
                    dropout_rate: 0.5
                }

                train_loss, _, value,gs = sess.run([loss, minimize, val1,global_step], train_data_feed)

                if iteration % 5 == 0:
                    print("Epoch: {}/{}".format(epoch_step, config.max_epoch),
                          "Iteration: {}".format(iteration),
                          "Train loss: {:.6f}".format(train_loss))
                iteration += 1

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, "checkpoints_sales/sales_pred.ckpt")

        # --------------------validation------------------------------------------------------

        with tf.Session(graph=config.graph) as sess:
            tf.set_random_seed(1)

            saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('checkpoints_sales'))

            test_data_feed = {
                inputs: val_X,
                dropout_rate: 1.0
            }

            test_pred = sess.run(prediction, test_data_feed)

            # rmsse = sess.run(correct_prediction, test_data_feed)

            pred_vals = rescle(test_pred)

            pred_vals = np.array(pred_vals)

            pred_vals = pred_vals.flatten()

            pred_vals = pred_vals.tolist()

            nonescaled_y = nonescaled_val_y.flatten()

            nonescaled_y = nonescaled_y.tolist()

            plot(nonescaled_y, pred_vals, "Sales Prediction VS Truth mv testSet.png")
            write_results(nonescaled_y, pred_vals, "Sales Prediction batch mv results_all validationSet.csv")

            meanSquaredError = mean_squared_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
            rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
            print("RMSE:", rootMeanSquaredError)
            mae = mean_absolute_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
            print("MAE:", mae)
            mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
            print("MAPE:", mape)
            rmse_val = RMSPE(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
            print("RMSPE:", rmse_val)

    # --------------------testing------------------------------------------------------

    with tf.Session(graph=config.graph) as sess:
        tf.set_random_seed(1)

        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('checkpoints_sales'))

        test_data_feed = {
            inputs: test_X,
            dropout_rate: 1.0
        }

        test_pred = sess.run(prediction, test_data_feed)

        # rmsse = sess.run(correct_prediction, test_data_feed)


        pred_vals = rescle(test_pred)

        pred_vals = np.array(pred_vals)

        pred_vals = (np.round(pred_vals, 0)).astype(np.int32)

        pred_vals = pred_vals.flatten()


        pred_vals = pred_vals.tolist()

        nonescaled_y = nonescaled_test_y.flatten()

        nonescaled_y = nonescaled_y.tolist()

        plot(nonescaled_y, pred_vals, "Sales Prediction VS Truth mv testSet.png")
        write_results(nonescaled_y, pred_vals, "Sales Prediction batch mv results_all validationSet.csv")

        meanSquaredError = mean_squared_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
        rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
        print("RMSE:", rootMeanSquaredError)
        mae = mean_absolute_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
        print("MAE:", mae)
        mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
        print("MAPE:", mape)
        rmse_val = RMSPE(nonescaled_y, pred_vals)
        print("RMSPE:", rmse_val)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_test()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using tf.layers.dropout the rate argument tells how much of the data to drop when you give 1.0 all the output is gone, replace 1.0 with 0.0 and it should work.
TensorFlow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout

Comment: I want to deactivate the dropout layer when validating and testing. Most stackoverflow posts said that putting 'rate=1.0' deactivated the layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971349/how-to-turn-off-dropout-for-testing-in-tensorflow This is why I put default rate as 1.0

Comment: Yes its confusing. tf.nn.dropout acts differently from tf.layer.dropout

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this because even though @Almog's answer was correct it didn't have the explanation I wanted. So for anyone confused like me:

If you use:

> 'tf.nn.dropout()'

to deactivate the dropout layer you should put

> keep_prob= 1.0 not keep_prob=0.0

as keep_prob means '**The probability that each element is kept**.' So keeping it as 1.0 makes sense to deactivate it.
If you are using

> 'tf.layers.dropout()'

you should put:

> rate=0.0 not rate=1.0

as rate here means 'The dropout rate (should be between 0 and 1). E.g. "rate=0.1" would drop out 10% of input units'. So if I put rate=0.0 it means that none of the input units will be dropped.